# Get webpack chunk name in babel-loader

Tags: webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I'm wondering if it's possible to get webpack's entry points and chunk names inside custom babel plugin in babel-loader.

Answer (score 0):

No because it won't have a chunk name yet since the chunk name is generated after all the loaders are applied and so on.

Also, you are not able to get the entrypoint since the only information that `babel-loader` is going to have is the source code to transpile and its options (declared on a babelrc file or on the options object).